# Pipx installation Problem / eth-brownie installation error

Tags: python, installation, solidity, brownie, pipx

Someone please help me with this error

after installing pipx successfully - `$ python3 -m pip install --user pipx` &&
`$ python3 -m pipx ensurepath`

*Successfully installed pipx-0.16.4*

when i run this command - `$ pipx install eth-brownie`

I'm getting this error - `$ bash: pipx: command not found`

Comment: What is the output when you run just `pipx`?

Comment: Try with `python3 -m pipx install eth-brownie`

Comment: commend -  `$ pipx`
return - `$ bash: pipx: command not found`

Answer (score 1):

Try using pip3 install eth-brownie. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `~/.local/pipx/` dir & uninstall `pipx` if needed. Then run again
`pipx install eth-brownie`. It just worked for me.

I'm making a github [gist](https://gist.github.com/Aviksaikat/d38ff126141f9f1e58329200b01e9015) so that everyone can fix this by just running this script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Error: Please provide exactly one argument."
  echo "Usage: {0} <package name>"
  exit 1
fi

rm -rf ~/.local/pipx/
# pip3 uninstall pipx
pipx install $1
```

- Make sure you have setup your path properly. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file
- `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`